# Creating a loop in java to read character then perform loop

Tags: java

Im trying to write a code that will read a character from the user. If they enter "y" it will perform the loop and calculate a square root. My square root function works fine. I need the loop to run until something other than "y" is entered. I keep getting this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Violation of: input is in double format
    at components.simplereader.SimpleReaderSecondary.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at Newton2.main(Newton2.java:58)

This is my code

```
    while (true) {
        out.print("Enter 'y' to calculate a square root: ");
        char a = in.read();
        if (a == 'y') {
            out.print("Enter a number to take square root of: "); //prompt the user
            double x = in.nextDouble(); //input a value to take the root of
            double answer = sqrt(x); //use the sqrt method to evaluate
            out.println("Estimate of square root: " + answer); //print the result
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Close input and output streams
     */
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: Can you show me the **in** variable? Is it a scanner? or What?

Comment: @Gatusko Looks like [`SimpleReaderSecondary`](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/software/common/doc/components/simplereader/SimpleReaderSecondary.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely problem is that you're inputting the number on the next line, but because you previously only read a single `char`, the number parser is choking on the newline character. Try this:

```
char a = in.read();
in.nextLine();  // move cursor to the next line
```

Related: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/1553851)

Comment: @AustinHartman Then please click the check to accept the answer.